# Yii2 using afterAction mehtod to fire js function

Tags: javascript, yii2, pushstate

I am trying to change my url with `historyPush` state but i want this to happen after the controller action is over. I know about the `afterAction` method from the documentation. But where should i place this method? Is it in the same  controller where my action stands? My js function is triggered on `select` element `onchange` like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3 sort-col hide-mobile">
    <select class="product-select" onchange="pjaxFilterForm(); reCreateUrl(this);" name="sort_price">
        <option value="" class="product-option" selected><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.sortprice')?></option>
        <option value="ASC" class="product-option"<?= ((isset($_GET['sort_price']) and $_GET['sort_price'] == 'ASC')) ? ' selected' : ''; ?>><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.orderPriceAsc');?></option>
        <option value="DESC" class="product-option"<?= ((isset($_GET['sort_price']) and $_GET['sort_price'] == 'DESC')) ? ' selected' : ''; ?>><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.orderPriceDesc');?></option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3 sort-col hide-mobile">
    <select class="product-select" onchange="pjaxFilterForm(); reCreateUrl(this);" name="sort_name">
        <option value="" class="product-option" selected><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.sortname')?></option>
        <option value="ASC" class="product-option"<?= ((isset($_GET['sort_name']) and $_GET['sort_name'] == 'ASC')) ? ' selected' : ''; ?>><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.orderNameAsc');?></option>
        <option value="DESC" class="product-option"<?= ((isset($_GET['sort_name']) and $_GET['sort_name'] == 'DESC')) ? ' selected' : ''; ?>><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.orderNameDesc');?></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

So the function is triggered on `onchage` event but i want to pause it until the controller action is over. (Now the function is executed before the action)
The whole idea is that i have few filters but when i change the `sort_name` filter and after that i try to change `sort_price` filter , the second one don't work. So if my url is like `?sort_price=&producer=&sort_name=DESC&view=1` and when the my js function my url becmomes like `?sort_price=ASC&producer=&sort_name=&view=1` and that is what i want to reach but after the controller action.
My js:

```
function reCreateUrl(e) {
        var elemName = e.name;
        var currUrl = window.location.href;
        var params = (currUrl.split('?')[1]).split('&');
        var url = "<?= $lang->url ?>/tashev-183?";
        for(var i=0; i<params.length; i++){
            var keyValuePair = params[i].split('=');
            if(keyValuePair[0] != elemName && keyValuePair[0] != "view" && keyValuePair[0] != "producer"){
                keyValuePair[1] = "";
                params[i] = [keyValuePair[0], keyValuePair[1]];
            }else{
                params[i] = [keyValuePair[0], keyValuePair[1]];
            }

            var urlPiece = params[i].join("=");
            if(i < params.length - 1){
                url += urlPiece + "&";
            }else{
                url += urlPiece;
            }
        }
        var stateObj = { prevPage: url };
        var path = '/' + url;
        history.pushState(stateObj, "category page", path);
    }
```

I know it becomes a little messy(because of me probably) but will be thankful for any advice! :)

Comment: You should be place `afterAction()` method in model.

Comment: Thank you! I am one step closer now i think :)